# Каким образом появляются скриншоты экрана входа без участия пользователя?

Tags: macos, взлом, screenshots

Днём без участия пользователя произошло 5 скриншотов с интервалами в 5, 2, 18, 1 секунд. Сейчас скрины на рабочем столе и имеют такие названия (LWScreenShot 2020-05-27 at 2.31.05 PM). Каким образом могли возникнуть эти скриншоты, может ли это быть взлом? Если взлом, то как посмотреть открытые порты, на какие обратить особое внимание?
P.S. Версия OS - MacOS High Sierra

Comment: Вопрос имеет какое-то отношение к программированию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в файлах изображения вашего окна блокировки / входа в систему, то в этом нет ничего страшного. Согласно [вот этой статье](https://osxdaily.com/2015/11/11/howto-take-screenshot-login-screen-mac-osx/), MacOS имеет функцию снятия скриншота окон блокировки / входа в систему по расписанию, либо хоткею (`Command + Shift + 3`). В результате на рабочем столе создаются файлы вида `LWScreenShot 2016-12-04 at 12.43.23 PM.png`.

Если вы сами этого не настраивали, то, возможно, кошка прошла по клавиатуре. Если кошки у вас нет, да и живете вы один, то есть повод задуматься.